# Why are the results of Maximum Likelihood and Maximum A Posterior with the same data different?

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

I have calculated MLE and MAP with the same data but the results were different but I don't understand why they have different results although I have used the same data. I just followed the way I need to calculate for the result of MLE and MAP.

Comment: Different inferential methods (MLE, moment estimator, bootstrap estimator, Bayesian estimators) return different estimates with the same data.

Answer (score 2):

Loosely speaking, the MAP uses the prior distribution to augment your observed sample, so in addition to calculating, say, $\bar{x}$ for the data, you estimate the population $\mu$ by including the prior distribution.

They’re different estimation methods. They should give different results, at least in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just wonder what you exactly meant by "augment".

Comment: Having a prior is like adding data to your sample. (Prior distributions aren’t magic, though. You can pick a bad prior.)

Comment: I can't really picture what you said above. How should I think of "having a prior is like adding to your sample"?